# Get deployment url to be passed to next step - Azure Static Web apps with Github actions

Tags: github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I am using Azure Static web apps with Github actions and I need the deployment URL to be passed into the next step.

Any idea how I can get it? The step **Get deployment URL** fails with an environment is null error. This is my yml file.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn config get cacheFolder)"

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: yarn-cache # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_HAPPY_RIVER_01F5A930F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "build" # Built app content directory - optional
        env:
          VITE_AG_GRID_LICENSE_KEY: ${{secrets.VITE_AG_GRID_LICENSE_KEY}}
          VITE_API_SCOPE: ${{secrets.VITE_API_SCOPE}}
          VITE_CLIENT_ID: ${{secrets.VITE_CLIENT_ID}}
          VITE_SOURCE_LOADER_BASE_URL: ${{secrets.VITE_SOURCE_LOADER_BASE_URL_DEV}}
          VITE_TENANT_ID: ${{secrets.VITE_TENANT_ID}}
      - name: Get deployment URL
        id: deployment
        uses: dorshinar/get-deployment-url@master
        timeout-minutes: 5
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - run: echo ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.deployment }}

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_HAPPY_RIVER_01F5A930F }}
          action: "close"
```

Comment: Github action `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy` already provides deployment URL as output parameter, I'm not sure what this other action does `dorshinar/get-deployment-url`? Why don't you get deployment URL from `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy` action?

Comment: Any idea how I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get URL as output parameter from `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy`:

```
...
- name: Build And Deploy
  id: builddeploy
  uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
...
- name: Print Deployment URL
  run: echo ${{ steps.builddeploy.outputs.static_web_app_url }}
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-deploy/blob/0407e359a606e89151694428fa2457e4ef646693/action.yml#L44) to action yml where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was giving an empty string like below.

`Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.`

I solved this by restarting my Azure AppService.

Be sure to check the failed build step, as this error might also be indication of an error.